# Connecting function to dynamically made QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Sorry, this question is probably duplicate but i have to ask since i can't make it work.

I am dynamically making `QPushButtons` with for loop like this.

```
 for (int var = 0; var < size; ++var) {
     QPushButton *copyr = new QPushButton("copy");
     ...
}
```

I am successfully adding those new widgets to layout but i cant bind an function on them.I am trying to connect that button on SLOT like as many sources on the internet had suggested:

```
connect (copyr , SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( c2c(txt) ) );
```

but i can't make it work, and i am kp getting an error like :

```
No such SLOT ClassName::c2c(txt)
```

event it's normally defined in .h file and it exists in .cpp file also.
Any ides why is this happening and how too fix it?

Comment: Are you using Qt5? If so, you really should be using the new signal/slot syntax.

Comment: `connect(copyr, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &ClassName::c2c);`

Comment: @dave  yes, i am using qt5, i am new to c++ programming , started 2-3 weeks ago, an project in order to learn it, so i am not familiar with new syntax. Only thing i can do is to google for answer or ask here if nothing is working. Also , that old syntax worked couple of times in this same project without any errors.

Comment: @JesperJuhl   It works, thanks, but how do you provide an argument  to c2c function in this syntax?

Comment: @DušanAtanacković You cannot connect a slot which takes an argument to a signal that doesn't provide one. You can either add a default argument to your slot, remove it altogether or use a lambda to fill it in.

Comment: The right approach depends on what your `txt` is supposed to be

Comment: its string, actually it's text received from QLineEdit.text().toStdString

Comment: But where does it come from and why do you want it to arrive at the slot? When the button sends its signal, it cannot possibly send some text from some QLineEdit with it.

Comment: I guess you can try connecting it to no-parameter lambda, inside of which you will get line edit text and pass it down the line - https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#Pros_2, https://medium.com/genymobile/how-c-lambda-expressions-can-improve-your-qt-code-8cd524f4ed9f

Comment: He could, but why not get the text from the QLineEdit from inside the slot? If you capture it in a lambda it will not change as the lineedit does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use the new syntax for connections:

```
connect(copyr, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &ClassName::c2c);
```

However, you cannot connect a signal that does not provide a parameter to a slot that expects one. Here, you have multiple options:

- Remove the parameter from the slot entirely and get the value from within the slot.
- Provide a default parameter in the slot declaration so it can be called without arguments
- Wrap the connection in a lambda if you want a parameter from the connecting code to arrive at the slot like this:

  `connect( copyr, &QPushButton::clicked, [this, txt](){ this->c2c(txt); } );`

Comment: Well, answer for all of yours questions from above is that i am new to c++ programming.I have used Qt, but as PyQt (e.g) in python and there was much easier .
I have succeed  to send parameter with lambda like this.

connect (copyr , &QPushButton::clicked, [=]{SuperFalcon::c2c(txt);} );

Your code work as well, thanks for your time.